# Bootstrap 4 Buttons Align-Middle of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image][image]I am quite new to Bootstrap 4. I can't seem to get my 3 buttons centered in the middle of the page. I am using Bootstrap-4. I feel it is something simple I am missing. Also is there a way to extend the buttons a little more outside the text, would I use padding for that? Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
    beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_index.css">
    </style>
    <title>Sanchez</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sanchez</a>

    <!--Toggle Button-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbar"aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-
      expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

    <!--Navbar links-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" a href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" 
     href="Sanchez_bootstrap_portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" 
     href="Sanchez_bootstrap_contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <div id="content">
   <div class="container text-center">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
     href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_about.html">Web 
     Developer</a>
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
      href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
      href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_contact.html">Contact</a>
      </<div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-
    KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script 


  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
    beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
    h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS
    body{
      background-image: url('images/background3.jpeg');

```
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-image: url('images/background3.jpeg');
}

html{
  height: 100%;
}
#content{
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share a screenshot of the web page and the problem to explain it better. Also, there are few points I would like to bring to attention.

1. Why are you not including jquery.min.js in the head when bootstrap nav depends on it to work? It should be before bootstrap src
2. You have a typo `</<div>` please check your code
3. What do mean by centering the buttons?

You mean centering side by side? like this: [image] or you mean centering as in stacked? [image]

For the former case, I used this code:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="container text-center" style = "vertical-align:middle;
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" >
   <div class="row" style = "line-height: 20em;">     
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4" style = "vertical-align: middle;">
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
     href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_about.html" >Web 
     Developer</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4" style = "vertical-align: middle;">
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
      href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_portfolio.html" >Portfolio</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4" style = "vertical-align: middle;">     
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
      href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_contact.html" >Contact</a>     
    </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the latter, I used:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
     href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_about.html" >Web 
     Developer</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
      href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_portfolio.html" >Portfolio</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">    
      <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" a 
      href="Sanchez_Bootstrap_contact.html" >Contact</a>     
    </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

4. For bootstrap divs, think about dividing divs in to subdivs and then give them elements. For col-lg-12, we have 12 blocks. If you want three inner elements, divide 12 by 3 which is 4. So wrap each of the three elements in col-lg-4. The width would be: 100/3 = 33.33% Similarly, if you want three elements with each 100% wide, wrap the three in each col-lg-12 div and each will have width of 100/1 = 100%
5. Its better to have a habit of specifying lg, sm, xs and md when you are writing the code itself and use a mobile first development methodology to think how its gonna look on each mobile devices right away. i.e. specify col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 in each div.

Note: I used your code in an ongoing project, so few css have been inherited form my code, like font width, button coloring, background etc

Comment: Hi There, I tried both codes and neither worked. I'm trying to make the buttons side-by side and in the middle of the webpage. I attached a photo and it was deleted. :( I'll try to attach again. I put the Jquery src file at the bottom because I was taught to put it at the very bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

Comment: I used the code and took screenshots of them working. Upload an image of the results you are getting. You can have it in the body and wait for the DOM to load but I always use jquery src before bootstrap src just to be sure.

Comment: I did the html doc, does the CSS need to change at all? I attached the image at the top of what I'm getting with your code.

Comment: @AlexandraA Changed the code a little. Try the new one now. [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGKNJR). row div should be inside a col-12 div itself. I put it outside before. My bad! :) Bootstrap by default adds padding of 15px to each div on sides, so you can play with it.

Comment: I put a column inside a column which was wrong before. It should be row inside a column and then columns inside that row

Comment: Looks great! Thanks! The only thing is I want the buttons "Web, Portfolio, Contact," etc. to be mid-point of the actual web page. Like evenly halfway down the webpage. Sorry to be asking all these questions but it's just about there! :)

Comment: @AlexandraA There are multiple ways of doing it. One of the ways I used is setting line height of parent and then using vertical align for each children. [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGKNJR). Have updated the code as well. You can wrap the inline styles into css later. To read more about vertical styling, here is a good [blog](http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)

Comment: If the final code is the right answer, you can accept it :)

Comment: Hi Saurav-  I suppose it will work. It's not completely middle of the screen but it did push down a little. You can see my photo up top for ref. I"m assuming there is something that is wrong in my CSS. I"m not sure why it won't align in the middle of the webpage.

Comment: Css is right. Contents are in the middle of the row div which has some line height and row div is not in the center. You are however accessing its position wrt the body's image. Wrap the code in a heroimage div instead and apply line height for that as well and you would be good to go. You gotta play with it now on